# what is the difference between tf.checkpoint.save() and tf.checkpointmanager.save() in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I wished to save an image-captioning model (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/image_captioning) using tf.checkpoints. What is the difference when i save the model using tf.checkpoint.save() and tf.checkpointmanager.save()? What kind of file is saved? Is it some kind of its own checkpoint file or what is it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`CheckpointManager` allows you to manage multiple checkpoints. `checkpoint.save()` will save only one checkpoint.

It is explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/CheckpointManager) in Tensorflow documentation

```
tf.train.CheckpointManager(
    checkpoint, directory, max_to_keep, keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=None,
    checkpoint_name='ckpt', step_counter=None, checkpoint_interval=None,
    init_fn=None
)
```